# Pause between repeats in an animation in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I have applied the following `FadeIn/FadeOut` animation to a `Canvas` in `WPF`.

```
var fadingInOutAnimation = new DoubleAnimation
{
    From = 1,
    To = 0,
    Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)),
    AutoReverse = true,
    RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever,
};

MyCanvas.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, fadingInOutAnimation);
```

Now I want it to pause for 1 second when it reaches the end of the animation before repeating again.

So it is like this:

```
Animation --- Pause (1 Sec) --- Animation --- Pause (1 Sec) and so on.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might add a Storyboard that does the auto-reversing and repetition, but that has a longer duration than the animation:

```
var fadeInOutAnimation = new DoubleAnimation()
{
    From = 1,
    To = 0,
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
};

var storyboard = new Storyboard
{
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
    AutoReverse = true,
    RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever
};

Storyboard.SetTarget(fadeInOutAnimation, MyCanvas);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fadeInOutAnimation,
                             new PropertyPath(Canvas.OpacityProperty));

storyboard.Children.Add(fadeInOutAnimation);
MyCanvas.BeginStoryboard(storyboard);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using BeginTime in the animation to initiate a pause between cycles.

```
<Storyboard TargetProperty ="(Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
            BeginTime ="00:00:00"
            RepeatBehavior ="Forever"
            AutoReverse="True">
<ColorAnimation From="Red" To="Yellow" 
            BeginTime="00:00:02"
            Duration="00:00:01"/>
</Storyboard>
```