# Repeating the whole animation

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation

I have a double animation which repeats three times. (a sort of shaking). And I want this procedure to repeat every 3 seconds. It is seams easy but I have absolutely no idea how to make it work.

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
        <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5 0.5" />
        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <RotateTransform />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded" >
                <BeginStoryboard Name="ImageShakeAnimation">
                    <Storyboard TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle">
                        <DoubleAnimation 
                            From="-3" To="3" Duration="0:0:0.05" 
                            AutoReverse="True"
                            RepeatBehavior="3x"
                            FillBehavior="Stop"
                           />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: @AyyappanSubramanian Done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the duration of the storyboard longer than the duration of the animation and set the repeatbehaviour of the storyboard also to forever.

For a similar solution look  at [Pause between repeats in an animation in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23586041/pause-between-repeats-in-an-animation-in-wpf)

Comment: <Storyboard TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle" Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever">  fixed the problem. Thank you very much